# Duplicates not being removed

Tags: java, file, arraylist

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    List<String> knownWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void readKnownWordsFile()
    {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("knownWords.txt");
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream2));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                knownWordsArrayList.add(strLine);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    public void readFile() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("newWords.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            String numberedLineRemoved = "";
            String strippedInput = "";
            String[] words;
            String trimmedString = "";
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                numberedLineRemoved = numberedLine(strLine);
                strippedInput = numberedLineRemoved.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
                if ((strippedInput.trim().length() != 0) || (!strippedInput.contains("")) || (strippedInput.contains(" "))) {
                    words = strippedInput.split("\\s+");
                    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                        if (words[i].trim().length() != 0) {
                            wordsArrayList.add(words[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < knownWordsArrayList.size(); i++) {
                wordsArrayList.add(knownWordsArrayList.get(i));
            }
            HashSet h = new HashSet(wordsArrayList);
            wordsArrayList.clear();
            wordsArrayList.addAll(h);
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsArrayList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(wordsArrayList.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println(wordsArrayList.size());
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String numberedLine(String string) {
        if (string.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return string;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.readKnownWordsFile();
        test.readFile();

    }

}
```

Adding to knownWordsArrayList from a file. Then I move on to another file and put the words into wordsArrayList. Then I make a hashSet to remove the duplicated words, but they're still there. For example, "Mrs" is in the knownWordsArrayList but when I print wordsArrayList, I still see "Mrs". I don't understand why the duplicated words are not being removed. Could it have to do with the character set?

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, "Mrs" is in the knownWordsArrayList but when I print wordsArrayList, I still see "Mrs".

Well yes, it would be. You're explicitly adding *all* the values from `knownWordsArrayList` to `wordsArrayList`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < knownWordsArrayList.size(); i++) {
      wordsArrayList.add(knownWordsArrayList.get(i));
 }
```

It's not really clear what your code is meant to be doing (use of whole-collection operations and the enhanced for loop would help in terms of clarity) but that's why everything in `knownWordsArrayList` is also in `wordsArrayList`.

Importantly, this statement:

> Then I make a hashSet to remove the duplicated words

... just means that each words will only be present once. That's all it will do.

I suspect you *should* remove the code I've quoted above, and instead do:

```
HashSet h = new HashSet(wordsArrayList);
h.removeAll(knownWordsArrayList);
wordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(h);
```

Comment: Yes, I explicitly combine the two lists so I can remove the duplicates. After that for loop you can see my hash which should remove the duplicates but it is not.

Comment: @NomanArain: No, it shouldn't. It should make sure that each word only occurs once. So if you start off with a list of { A, B, B } and then create a hash set from that, it will have { A, B }. I think you've misunderstood what `HashSet` does.

Comment: So then knownWordsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(h); leaves me with all the new words?

Comment: @NomanArain: Sorry, that was meant to be assigning to `wordsArrayList` instead of `knownWordsArrayList`. I've edited it now. (I'd strongly advise you to remove the `ArrayList` suffix from all your variables, by the way. It'll make the code much simpler to read.)

Comment: I see, I thought it was a good thing because eclipse tends to do it.

Comment: How can I remove ignoring case?

Comment: Actually, I got umlauts and fÜr got changed to fãœr. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] arr = { "kitty", "mitty", "kitty" };
    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(hs);
```

and the output is:

```
[kitty, mitty, kitty]
[mitty, kitty]
```

is this what you expected or not?

Comment: Hey thank you, but Jon Skeet answered the question and helped fixed the problem.